# PaintComponent method not getting called

Tags: java, swing

I wrote the following code. Everything works fine. There are no compilation errors. yet I see only a yellow window and nothing else. I am posting my paintcomponent method here.

**my paintcomponent method**

```
  @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(x,100,150,200);
        fh++;
    }
    }
```

**I** tried extending Jpanel,JFrame,Jcomponent,etc
I tried paint() as well as paintComponent()

I am adding full code for reference
**my code**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

class painting extends JPanel
{static Component c=new Canvas();
 static JFrame f=new JFrame();
 int fh;
 int x=50;
    public void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
   {
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(c);
     f.setVisible(true);   
     f.setSize(300,320);

     /*
     c.setSize(200,220);
     c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
     c.setForeground(Color.red);
     c.setVisible(true);
     */
     for(;x<200;x++)
     {x=x+10;
     repaint();
     Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(x,100,150,200);
        fh++;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please restore your entire code in your question.  The answer to your problem lies in that code, not in your paintComponent method.

Comment: please tell me if you require the full code and please tell me how to do so

Comment: We require the full code.  Your question originally contained that code.  Please edit your question again and place the entire code for your class in your question, just like you originally posted it.

Comment: sorry for all hat I read somewhere that we must not post the entire code unnecessarily and that's why I removed it

Comment: I would recommend you not add `AWT` components to `Swing` components as the results may be unpredictable.  Instead of using `Canvas` you can just use a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` if you want to do some drawing or painting.

Answer (score 0):

A component’s `paintComponent` method is only called if that component is added to a window.  You added a `new Canvas()` to your window, but you never added an instance of your own specialized panel, `painting`, to your window.

You can fix it by removing this:

```
static Component c=new Canvas();
```

and replacing this:

```
f.add(c);
```

with this:

```
f.add(new painting());
```

Comment: Please also help me with the repaint method

Comment: I regret to inform you that the component c had an important role in creating the background color.Even when i added both i am still stuck with repaint()

Comment: No, it will not work.  You have defined a new type of component (the `painting` class) with customized painting behavior.  You must make use of an instance of that component in order to see that behavior.  No other component’s built-in paintComponent method will invoke your paint code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will check it out and post the correct code

Comment: If you want to post the correct code, ***add*** it to the end of your question;  do not overwrite your original code!  The question will not be useful to future readers if they cannot see what the problem was.